# Creating a Linked List ; " what is node* next "?

Tags: c++

In

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

struct node
{
    int data;
    node *next;
};
```

What does `node *next ;` mean?

Comment: What book are you learning C++ from?  This should be covered by every good learning resource.

Comment: Next can keep the address of another node object. This way it enables your algorithms to traverse through the nodes of a list.

Comment: Please read the tag descriptions before applying them to your question. I have removed the [`dsa`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dsa) tag that you had incorrectly applied.

Comment: I highly recommend purchasing a Data Structures book that has examples in C++.

Comment: It's the "link" part of linked list.

Comment: Actually the Reason i add `DSA` tag was, I'm learning Linked List in DSA course. I got it now though this is different From Data Structures

Answer (score 3):

It means that the `struct` called `node` has an element called `next` that is of the type "pointer to `node`". In a linked list, such an element is typically used to point to the next entry in the linked list.

Comment: Each `node` points to the *next* `node` in the list. That is what makes it a linked list.

Comment: thanks for help , actually my doubt is that is `next` a constructor ? what is constructor.

Comment: @VishwaroopGangarde • You are asking about very fundamental and introductory concepts in C++.  It appears you are in need of a [good C++ book](https://stackoverflow.com/a/388282/4641116).